# How can an empty change set be possible in a revision history

Tags: discussion, revision-history

I look at a question's [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/1110171/revisions) and see one of its change sets is empty.

How can an empty change set be possible?

> [image: Empty Change set]

Comment: Although Robert claims he edited tags, in the database it looks like he didn't, looking at [this query](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/331318).

Comment: I assume the tag he removed no longer exists and / or has been blacklisted.

Comment: @TZHX if that is true it would still be in the posthistory table as [this query](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/331322) proves....

Comment: I'm guessing that maybe it didn't use to populate the ***Edit removed during grace period message***, thus he added/removed a tag, and then decided to add/remove it back within the 5 minute grace period. Thus leaving the automatic ***edited tags*** description, but showing no tags changed. For example, I added the "tags" tag to your question, then went to edit again, and gives that [first message](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/298394/revisions) now, but maybe it didn't use to do that.

Answer (score 2):

As per CRABOLO's [comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/298394/how-can-be-a-empty-change-set-is-possible-in-a-revision-history#comment215756_298394), the user trying to make a change and removed it shortly.

It was a tag change and it was removed with in the grace period *5 mins*. So the revision description is as *edited tags* and no tag change is affected.

Comment: CRABOLO's comment was correct in that the "edit removed" thing seems to not always have appeared, but it _also_ appears that reverting your edit before the message was implemented would flat remove the revision, as if it never existed. See [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/133301/undone-edits-disappear-from-revision-history/180564#180564) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/133294/how-long-can-you-change-your-vote/133297#133297) for example. This was fixed _after_ this edit, so... This becomes unlikely, and was a very odd glitch if it actually is what happened.